# Rails validates_acceptance_of :accept => true or "1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use `validates_acceptance_of` for tos on my user model. I need it to work for a new API endpoint which could be true, but also not to regress on older workings ("1").

Is there a way to say `validates_acceptance_of tos, accept: [true, "1"]`

Note: I've tried the line above and it fails for both.

Answer (score 0):

`validates_acceptance_of :tos, accept: true` should work for both values `true` or `"1"`.

From the Rails docs:

> :accept - Specifies value that is considered accepted. The default
>   value is a string "1", which makes it easy to relate to an HTML
>   checkbox. This should be set to true if you are validating a database
>   column, since the attribute is typecasted from "1" to true before
>   validation.

Source:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_acceptance_of